# react-add-to-calendar all day event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm using [react-add-to-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-add-to-calendar) package to render "add to my calendar" button on my app.

On their [documentation](https://jasonsalzman.github.io/react-add-to-calendar/) you can find examples for the right way of passing event to their component. The only issue I have is how to pass `startTime` and `endTime` to notify my event is an all day event. I tried some options manually and to format my dates with momentJS but I failed to find the right way of doing it (if there is a one)

Hope someone has already dealt with this problem.

```js
import React from "react";
import moment from 'moment';
import AddToCalendar from 'react-add-to-calendar';

let icon = { 'calendar-plus-o': 'left' };

class Calendar extends React.Component {

    createEvent = () => {
        const {finalDate} = this.props;

      // when i tried to format my date
      // const startTime = moment(finalDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      // const endTime = moment(finalDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        return {
            title: "My event",
            description: "my all day event",
            location: 'Portland, OR',
            startTime: "2020-06-21",
            endTime: "2020-06-21"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AddToCalendar
                event={this.createEvent()}
                buttonTemplate={icon}
            />
        );
    };
}

export default Calendar;
```

**edit**: they just don't support this option.

Comment: that library's author deprecated it, is it still working for the latest `material-ui` library?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set

```
{
    startTime: '2020-06-21T00:00:00',
    endTime: '2020-06-21T23:59:59'
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it, it didn't work and also converted the date to two different days. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think all day events are supported; c.f. https://github.com/jasonsalzman/react-add-to-calendar/blob/master/src/helpers/index.js#L67

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite some old question.

Still, in case anybody is struggeling and since the referenced code is no longer maintained:

Check out my open-source solution (also supporting all-day events): https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button